# What does uptime command results mean

Tags: unix, console, terminal

If i call uptime on my server via shell i get string like this:

```
# uptime
22.23.23 up 5 days, 51 min, 3 users, load average 34.32 16.08 5.07
```

what does this part mean **load average 34.32 16.08 5.07** exactly - 
why three digits? does it mean three cores or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the load averages over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes, they are not related to your cores.

From the man page:

```
uptime gives a one line display of the following information.  The
current time, how long the system has been running, how many users
are currently logged on, and the system load averages for the past
1, 5, and 15 minutes.
```

For more information see [man uptime](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?uptime%281%29).

Comment: But what does "system load averages" mean, exactly?